# Android Java code to set redirect to new activity after login?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Hi I have an android app created which is a basic login screen which I want to take you to a new activity screen if logged in correctly. However I am having trouble with the redirect. Here is my code:

```
package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   private EditText  username=null;
   private EditText  password=null;
   private TextView attempts;
   private Button login;
   int counter = 3;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
      password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
      attempts = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
   }

   public void login(View view){
      if(username.getText().toString().equals("mara") && 
      password.getText().toString().equals("mara")){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login Successful!", 
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomePage.class));
       }    
   else{
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Credentials",
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       attempts.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);  
      counter--;
      attempts.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
      if(counter==0){
         login.setEnabled(false);
      }

   }

}
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }

}
```

At the moment if you login with the wrong credentials everything works as it should but if you login correctly the app just exits and says that it has stopped working. I know the problem it with my startActivity intent because if I remove

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomePage.class));
```

it at least puts up the toast to notify you that you have logged in correctly. Thanks!

Here is the code for the HomePage:

```
package com.example.loginscreen;

import android.widget.ImageView;

public class HomePage extends MainActivity{
ImageView image;

public void addListenerOnButton() {

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}
}
```

Comment: what is the error in your logcat?

Comment: Have you registered HomePage.java in manifest? Mostly that seems to be the error.

Comment: I'm surprised people don't use the convention that you put "Activity" at the end of the class's name of an Activity.

Comment: ok I now have added to manifest so it is  
         <activity
         android:name="com.example.loginscreen.MainActivity"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
       </activity>
       <activity
         android:name="com.example.loginscreen.HomePage"
         android:label="@string/app_name" >
       </activity>
I log in it just puts the toast up but then redirects to the main activity not homepage.

Comment: @user3478524 seems fine. Working now?

Comment: please see comment edit thanks

Comment: Have you extended activity in HomePage.java? @user3478524

Comment: Please share code of HomePage.java as well.

Comment: Yes HomePage extends MainActivity

Comment: @user3478524 you need to extend Activity, not MainActivity. check answer, and tell if that works. That should work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly,

register `HomePage` activity in manifest.

And

change

```
public class HomePage extends MainActivity{
}
```

to

```
public class HomePage extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey yes this worked thanks, HomePage isn't displaying anything now though any ideas?

Comment: @user3478524 for showing anything in activity, you need one xml file which contains its content. Check edited answer.

Comment: @user3478524 Refer to [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/). Its a very good link for beginners :)